# Key Vault Reference in Azure Function not resolved

Tags: azure-functions

I'm trying to access an Azure Key Vault secret from an Azure Function (v4 C# .NET 6.0) using the "reference" syntax.

When the app is hosted in Azure, it works as expected, i.e the secret value is retrieved.

However, I can't get it working when running locally (pressing F5 in Visual Studio). Rather than the secret value, I get the raw string `"@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://<MyKeyvaultName>.vault.azure.net/secrets/MySecret/)"`.

Is this supposed to work when developing in Visual Studio? The official documentation isn't helping me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references.

If not, what's the supported way of accessing a key vault secret in an Azure Function while developing? I can't get the usual `.AddAzureKeyVault()` working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed you added the key vault secret into azure function configurations, then az func auto read the secret from key vault and save the value into an environment variable. Actually, your app read the env variable value.

While developing, you can save the secret value in somewhere like appsettings.json, or even in environment variables directly.

The key vault reference syntax seems doesn't work in local.